# swiftUI - how to pass core data values of an item from ForEach list in NavigationLink to Detail view

Tags: core-data, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-ontapgesture

I just cannot figure out how to pass core data values of an item from ForEach list in NavigationLink to Detail view. Here is the code that got error: "Cannot convert value of type 'FetchedResults.Element' (aka 'FileEnt') to expected argument type 'FileViewModel'"

```
struct FileList: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(entity: FileEnt.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "fileName", ascending: false)]) var results: FetchedResults<FileEnt>

    @ObservedObject var fileData : FileViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(results) { aFile in
                    NavigationLink(destination: FileDetails(fileData: aFile), label: {
                    // ** error on red-underscored aFile above.
                            Text(aFile.fileName ?? "")
                    })
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Files")
        }
    }
}
```

FileViewModel is for Add, Edit and Detail views. Here is its simplified version for the question:

```
class FileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fileName = ""
    
    init(){

    }

    func DetailItem(fileItem: FileEnt){
        fileName = fileItem.fileName ?? ""
    }
}
```

FileDetails:

```
struct FileDetails: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var fileData : FileViewModel
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @State var isEdit = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                HStack {
                    Text("File Name:")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(fileData.fileName)
                ....
```

Modified the post for easy understanding. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You should pass `aFile` to the destination view in the `NavigationLink`

Comment: Tried. one like this: "NavigationLink(destination: FileDetails(fileData: fileData.DetailItem(fileItem: aFile))), got error of "Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'FileViewModel'".  Others generate more errors. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: No, I don’t understand the point of FileViewModel and why it is a StateObject in the FileList view. Why not pass and use `aFile` directly?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson, I don't know how, modified my question for the questions.

Comment: Did you also change FileDetails so it takes a FileEnt as argument?

Comment: It uses same: @ObservedObject var fileData : FileViewModel
Added FileDetails in the post. the error is on FileList side, right?

Comment: resolved it with a different approach